# System.Text.Json problem with large list serialization

Tags: json, asp.net-core, serialization

I wanted to remove Newtonsoft from my project and start using the default System.Text.Json. Now I have a very large list of objects which I want to serialize, but this doesn't work in System.Text.Json, but it does work in Newtonsoft.

The problem is that the JSON is 'cut off' after +- 58000 characters. So the JSON is not valid anymore.

This works:

```
return Ok(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result, new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
        }));
```

I tried to change the max settings in my web.config, but this didn't fix it. Are there any other settings which I could implement?

Thanks in advance!

Evert

Comment: You need to elaborate what "doesn't work" mean. Are you getting an exception? If so, then show us the exception. Does it hang? If so then say that and gives some more numbers on amount of objets/number of properties per object.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I forgot the most important part... I 'completed' the question. I hope it's clear this way.

Comment: Do you have any update? Since I failed to reproduce your issue, so I haven't made out if it worked or not. Pls kindly let me know your test result.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't reproduce the issue, I make up a model which had a string  variable, and the string has a 9999999 length, then it can be converted successfully.

Then I scan `JsonSerializerSettings` definition and found method below which will throw `ArgumentException` which seems to relate to your issue. So i'm afraid you can try the set `MaxDepth`.

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the maximum depth allowed when reading JSON. Reading past this depth will throw a <see cref="JsonReaderException"/>.
        /// A null value means there is no maximum.
        /// The default value is <c>64</c>.
        /// </summary>
        public int? MaxDepth
        {
            get => _maxDepthSet ? _maxDepth : DefaultMaxDepth;
            set
            {
                if (value <= 0)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("Value must be positive.", nameof(value));
                }

                _maxDepth = value;
                _maxDepthSet = true;
            }
        }
```